# Javascript: prompt user to order pizza toppings, assign price to toppings and alert total?

Tags: loops, for-loop, alert, prompt

This is my professor's assignment, to make a pizza menu:
The price of the pizza will be $10 plus extra for each topping:
    cheese: $2; tomato $1, mushrooms $3 and peppers $1

use prompts to select three toppings of the five into an array

use a for loop and if tests to compute the total price of the pizza

use an alert to report your toppings and the array

use another alert to report your bill and the price

**what I don't understand is how to use a 'for loop' to compute the prices for all the toppings the user entered through the prompt**

here is my js code so far:

```
var pizza = 10
var toppings = [];
var price = [];

var t1 = "cheese";
var p1 = 2;

var t2 = "tomato";
var p2 = 1;

var t3 = "mushrooms";
var p3 = 3;

var t4 = "peppers";
var p4 = 1;

toppings.push(t1);
toppings.push(t2);
toppings.push(t3);
toppings.push(t4);

price.push(p1);
price.push(p2);
price.push(p3);
price.push(p4);

var meow = [];
var m1 = prompt("Choose a desired topping: cheese, tomato, mushrooms, or peppers");
var m2 = prompt("Choose another desired topping: cheese, tomato, mushrooms, or peppers");
var m3 = prompt("Choose another desired topping: cheese, tomato, mushrooms, or peppers");

meow.push(m1);
meow.push(m2);
meow.push(m3);

var total = [];
var desired = [];

for (var i = 0; i < toppings.length; i++) {
   for (var i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
       desired.push(toppings[i] + price[i]);
   }
}

total.push(desired + pizza);
alert(total);
```

Comment: loop over meow (`meow.length`), grab the price for the topping in meow, and then add it to a total variable (which shouldn't be an array. it should  be a number that starts at 0)

Comment: There are a few issues here in that you don't check that the user inputs a valid topping, and you don't check that the toppings aren't all the same. Those can be fixed later though, after this price thing.

Comment: I would suggest using an associative array to map the toppings to the prices, instead of two separate arrays. `var pricesForToppings = {"cheese" : 2, "tomato" : 1, "mushrooms" : 3, "peppers": 1};`. Then, when the user inputs the topping, you can grab the price by saying `pricesForToppings["cheese"]` or `pricesForToppings[m1]`, and it will give you the price. You can then check if a topping is valid: `if ("anchovies" in pricesForToppings)` will be false, but `if ("cheese" in pricesForToppings)` will be true.

Comment: Also, jyrkim pointed out, see this jfiddle to see why you should use `j` instead of `i` in your inner loop (you'll have to hit f12 in chrome and go to the console to see the output): http://jsfiddle.net/k79tpf5r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is almost there, because there's only a couple of small changes you need to  to make to get your code working:

1. instead of using `var total[]` array use ordinary variable: `var total`
2. for the outer loop use the `meow` array instead of `toppings` array
3. (optional) you can either use `price` or `toppings` array as the inner
   array

```js
var pizza = 10
var toppings = [];
var price = [];

var t1 = "cheese";
var p1 = 2;

var t2 = "tomato";
var p2 = 1;

var t3 = "mushrooms";
var p3 = 3;

var t4 = "peppers";
var p4 = 1;

toppings.push(t1);
toppings.push(t2);
toppings.push(t3);
toppings.push(t4);

price.push(p1);
price.push(p2);
price.push(p3);
price.push(p4);

var meow = [];
var m1 = prompt("Choose a desired topping: cheese, tomato, mushrooms, or peppers");
var m2 = prompt("Choose another desired topping: cheese, tomato, mushrooms, or peppers");
var m3 = prompt("Choose another desired topping: cheese, tomato, mushrooms, or peppers");

meow.push(m1);
meow.push(m2);
meow.push(m3);

var total = 0;
var desired = [];

for (var i = 0; i < meow.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < toppings.length; j++) {
        if (meow[i] == toppings[j]) 
            total = total + price[j];
    }
}

//total.push(desired + pizza);
alert("total " + total);
```

Please note I think it's a good practice to have different variables for inner and outer for loops: `j` and `i`

Comment: It's not just good practice, it's required (in a sane world). In this jfiddle, 7,8,9 is only printed out once, instead of 3 times: http://jsfiddle.net/k79tpf5r/

Comment: On the other hand, this will loop forever and break the browser: http://jsfiddle.net/k79tpf5r/1/

Comment: @MillieSmith thanks for your comment, and sorry for the late reply - I'm living in different time-zone, probably :-) Well, the answer to your question: you are right. The above code shouldn't be used in production and etc. I think my answer is only useful for solving the problem addressed in the above question made by seasons986. I guess it would be practical to somehow make the above solution a more dynamic, ie. the user can decide whether to give 1 or more of toppings.